# Grep and substitute?

Tags: ksh

I have to parse ASCII files, output the relevant data to a comma-delimited file and load it into a database table.

The specs for the file format have been recently updated and one section is causing problems. This is the original layout for that section.

```
CSVHeaderAttr:PUIS,IdleImmediate,POH,Temp,WorstTemp
CSVValuesAttr:NO,NO,9814,31,56
```

I parse it with `grep` thusly

```
CSVAttributes=$(grep ^CSVValuesAttr:  ${filename}|cut -d':' -f2)
[ -z "$CSVAttributes" ] && CSVAttributes="NA"
```

It works great but now that the section has new fields and they are named differently

```
CSVHeaderAttr:PUIS,IdleImmediateSupported,IdleImmediateEnabled,POH,Temp,WorstTemp
CSVValuesAttr:NO,YES,YES,23861,31,51
```

Right now, I am grepping the files based on their layout (there is a field in the the header which tells me the version of the layout) to two different comma-delimited files and load them into two different tables. I would like to output both sections to the same file so the data scientist only has one table to use in his analysis.

Is there a way to use grep to produce an output like this and substitute empty fields with NA?

For one file type:

```
CSVHeaderAttr:PUIS,IdleImmediate,IdleImmediateSupported,IdleImmediateEnabled,POH,Temp,WorstTemp
CSVValuesAttr:NO,NO,NA,NA,9814,31,56
```

For the other file type:

```
CSVHeaderAttr:PUIS,IdleImmediate,IdleImmediateSupported,IdleImmediateEnabled,POH,Temp,WorstTemp
CSVValuesAttr:NO,NA,YES,YES,23861,31,51
```

Thanks for your input.

Comment: if you really have to stay in a shell to do this, the read up about `while read -d, var1 var2 ... ; do ... ; done < $inputFile` ELSE, this much easier to do this in `awk`. See http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '/CSVHeaderAttr:/ c\
CSVHeaderAttr:PUIS,IdleImmediate,IdleImmediateSupported,IdleImmediateEnabled,POH,Temp,WorstTemp
/CSVValuesAttr:/ {
      /\([^,]*,\)\{5\}/ s/\([^,]*,\)/&NA,/
      t p
      s/\(\([^,]*,\)\{2\}\)/\1NA,NA,/
#      t p
: p
   p
   }' AllYourFiles > ConcatFile
```

using sed that test how many column (with `/\([^,]*,\)\{5\}/`) before changing the new layout